# Where to start: Python script that lets a user rank elements against each other by comparison

Tags: python, sorting

Where I work, we do resume reviews of candidates. I want to be as fair as I can when I review, but I can't help but feel that I just sort of rank every resume against an arbitrary one in my head, and see how close the one in front of my fits to my ideal.

To fix that, I'm trying to write a code that

1) Shows two resumes to the user

2) User picks whichever one is better

3) Program says, "This resume is always above the other in a ranking"

4) Steps 1-3 are repeated

5) Eventually, each resume has been sorted to be roughly in the right position (doesn't have to be 100% perfect), and then the review continues.

Hopefully, this can take a bit of the bias out of the system and make resume reviews fairer. I'm sure that's something we all want.

My problem is that I'm just not sure where to start. I'm probably not using the correct search terms, but whenever I look for "how to manually sort with python" or "pick an element and sort in python," nothing really comes up.

I'm not as worried about the interface part right now: I just want to get a running start at the back end so that I can add an UI later.

As for my background in Python, I've got the basics down and I can learn whatever I need to learn (I've done arbitrage coding, stuff with selenium, scraping, and various bioinformatics things). Call it beginning stage of intermediate coder.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: When you say "shows 2 resumes", do you select which resumes to compare? Or are they selected programmatically?

Comment: @Aggragoth They would be picked programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You have a ton of options with how you want to implement this, but I think essentially you'll want to implement a sorting algorithm where the user does the comparisons between items.

Here's an example with bubble sort, which is easy to implement but not optimal. Choosing merge sort would minimize the number of comparisons the user has to do.

```
def bubble_sort_resumes(resume_list):
    n = len(resume_list)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n-i-1):
            if user_decides_if_the_first_resume_is_better(resume_list[j], resume_list[j+1]):
                resume_list[j], resume_list[j+1] = resume_list[j+1], resume_list[j]

def user_decides_if_the_first_resume_is_better(resume1, resume2):
    # todo: implement me
    # return True if resume1 is better, False if resume2 is better
```

I don't particularly recommend you choose bubble sort over other sorting algorithms, it's just easy.

There's also a fundamental assumption here that resumes can be evaluated into a single variable, which probably isn't true--people can have strengths in some areas and weaknesses in others. But it sounds like you're comfortable making that assumption for simplicity.

A problem you may run into is that if a user says (or would say): resume 1 is better than 2, resume 2 is better than 3, and resume 3 is better than 1, it's unclear how that case should be handled.

Comment: Since the comparisons are done manually, certainly an algorithm that does less comparisons would be better?

Comment: I agree you can do nlogn comparisons with merge sort instead of n^2 comparisons here, but how do you intend to do better than that? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the software to have a voting system so it can count how many times you chose a resume over another. **Dictionaries** are the best tool to use for this.

Suppose I have 3 resumes in a folder. The resumes are titled from 1.pdf to 3.pdf

1 - Use `os.listdir("PATH/TO/FOLDER/)` This will list all the titles of your resumes in a list.

2 - Convert the list to a dictionary. The dictionary keys will be the resume titles, and their values will be 0s in the beginnning. Eventually, the values will refelect how many votes each resume received.

3 - Create a nested for loop to compare resumes with each other.

4 - Everytime the user chooses a resume over another, the value for the resume will increase by 1.

```
#resumes = os.list(Path/To/Folder)

resumes = ["1.pdf","2.pdf", "3.pdf"]

resumeDictionary = { i : 0 for i in resumes } #Convert list to dictionary and give all keys a value 0

resumeRecord=[] #List to keep a record of resume comparison combinations

for resume in resumes:
    for Anotherresume in resumes:
        if Anotherresume is resume or [resume,Anotherresume] in resumeRecord or [Anotherresume,resume] in resumeRecord: #Prevent duplicate/repeated resume comparisons
            continue
        userInput = input("Which resume do you prefer? Press 1 or 2\n[1] " + resume + "\n" + "[2] " + Anotherresume + "\n")
        if int(userInput) == 1:
            resumeDictionary[resume] += 1
        elif int(userInput) == 2:
            resumeDictionary[Anotherresume] += 1
        resumeRecord.append([resume,Anotherresume]) #Record combination

print(resumeDictionary)
```

If I ran the code above and chose resume "1.pdf" 3 times, I end up with a dictionary like this

```
{'1.pdf': 3, '2.pdf': 1, '3.pdf': 2}
```

Comment: you'll compare every value twice in your implementation and also it's unclear why "Dictionaries are the best tool to use for this"

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out :) , I fixed the code. Regarding dictionaries, because the whole idea of a dictionary is to have a set of data linked to another set of data which is appropriate for an application that aims to store resumes and their vote counts. This makes modifying/Looking up dictionary keys much easier than other non primitive data structures.